# How to hide the control in the player using mediaelementjs.com

Tags: javascript, html, mediaelement.js

I would like to only show the control bar when user hover the mouse over the video using mediaelementjs.com player. I think there should be some function written already. But I can't find anywhere. Otherwise, should i just do simple show-hide in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Is this for desktop or "mobile" browsers?

Comment: I'm wondering this as well. Anybody!?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I added the `visibility: hidden` property on the following existing CSS selector:

```
.mejs-container .mejs-controls { visibility:hidden; }
```

It seems to work well. The controls now appear hovering the video, and not on page load.